# Creating View Count Feature in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Sorry for poor English, it is my second language.
I am currently using Next.js 14.0.3 and MUI.
Follow code is my page.js rendering in server side. Now I am trying to create a view count feature.

```
export default async function CharacterInfo(props) {
  const characterName = decodeURIComponent(props.params.id);
  const data = await fetch(
    `https://example.com/${props.params.id}`,
    requestOptions
  ).then((res) => res.json());
  if (data.detail) {
    return <NotFound />;
  }

  return (
    <Box>
      <CharBasic id={props.params.id} data={data} />
      <CharInfo id={props.params.id} data={data} />
    </Box>
  );
}
```

I was trying to add code something like this, but as I explained my page.js is SSR. In this case, how do I implement it?

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (!Cookies.get(`characterViewed_${characterId}`)) {

      Cookies.set(`characterViewed_${characterId}`, 'true', { expires: 1 });
    }
  }, [characterId]);
```